# Como hacer un vista sin iframe o similar

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo en **midominio.com**:

```
function envio(){
    var Typo_1 = document.getElementById('IP').value;


    var perimetros = {
        'button_sign_up'   : '127.0.0.1'
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: perimetros,
        url: 'http://midominio.com/func.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#per').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que quiero es que se vea lo de Otro dominio sin un iframe si es posible mediante ajax seria bueno. O ¿que opcion tengo? la necesidad

Comment: No tienes muchas opciones. Es eso, o habilitar una API en el otro sitio y re-renderizar el contenido en tu sitio. Puedes obtener el HTML del otro sitio de múltiples formas, pero no lograrás lo que buscas porque necesitas cargar también los recursos (CSS, JS).

Comment: tengo para hacer todo en ambos sitios.desde la edicion web y todo de hecho vi algo y lo que me interesa son variables de texto si CSS ni JS eso no cambia es lo de menos.

Comment: En ese caso puedes utilizar este método que mencionan en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737669/4710386. Puedes modificar ambas funciones para que reciban el URL que deseas. Pero si trabajas con el HTML del otro sitio, deberás procesarlo antes para remover al menos el ```<head>``` y los ```<script>```. Lo correcto sería más bien habilitar una API en el segundo sitio y obtener solo los datos, y renderizar con tu propio HTML en éste.

Comment: ¿Eres el administrador del otro dominio? Si es así debes configurar las [cabeceras `Access-Control-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) para que te permita obtener los datos desde `midominio.com`. En caso contrario obtendrás errores por violación de la seguridad de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).